# How do I strip HTML whitespace in ERB templates?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

Is there a way to strip HTML whitespaces in ERB templates, using Sinatra?

The Slim engine does it out-of-the-box, but I don't know how can ERB do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinatra lets you create your own middleware, a possible solution (that works for me) is to create a custom class (middleware in Sinatra's terms) and use it. The custom class uses a regexp to remove all whitespaces, respecting the content:

```
class ObfuscateHTML
  def initialize(app, options = {})
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

    if headers["Content-Type"] =~ /\bhtml\b/
      response[0] = response[0].gsub(/\s*(<[^>]+>)\s*/, '\1')
      headers["Content-Length"] = response[0].size.to_s
    end

    [status, headers, response]
  end
end

use ObfuscateHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below regular expression to strip whitespaces from HTML. It's not preferable method (due to HTML's nature that is not fit for regular expressions). But, it works well.

```
(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])\s{2,}(?=[<])|(?<=[>])\s{2,11}(?=[<])|(?=[\n])\s{2,}
```

Comment: where must I put that regular expression in my Sinatra app?

Comment: I'm not a Ruby nor Sinatra app user. But, if you can use any regular expression just before outputting your HTML output, just use above pattern and remove any matched sub string. It works well for our CMS product which is written in C#. But, above pattern is not C# specific of course.

Comment: Good work! The first `(?<=[^])` may raises error in ruby. I am using `(?<=[\^])`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Rack::Deflater](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/deflater.rb) middleware to gzip compress (regular HTTP stuff).

How to use the middleware: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Rack%20Middleware

Comment: maybe "compress" was not a good word, I mean delete whitespaces, I have edited the question

Comment: I have switched "compress" to "obfuscate" to better explain the problem

Comment: You can't really obfuscate HTML.  GZIP compression will go a lot further than stripping whitespace. If the intention is to make the markup harder to read, you're kidding yourself; all I need to do is tidy the markup (or use a DOM inspector for that matter).

Comment: I think it's possible. I have implemented a custom middleware, take a look at my answer. It works perfectly.

Comment: nonetheless my intention is not to make the markup harder to read, it's just a personal exercise, of course gzip is better to optimize bandwidth, but I'm not asking for strip vs gzip